# Increase font size and colour in android listview

Tags: android, android-listview, font-size

```
strTitle[i]=strarrNombre[i]+"\n"+strarrTitulo[i]+"\n"+strarrResumen[i]+"\n"+strarrCondiciones[i];
```

How do I set different font sizes and colours for each string? I am binding `strTitle[i]` to listview. Its running but it displays text values with same size. I want to display different font sizes and colousr for each string?

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML formatting. i.e:

```
strTitle[i] = "<html>" + strarrNombre[i] + "<br/>" + strarrTitulo[i] + "<br/>" + strarrResumen[i] + "<br/>" + strarrCondiciones[i] + "</html>";
```